# Getting Error in user Login in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I try to log-in in this code getting some error.

Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.3

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)#Error in this line
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'Login/login.html', context)
```

Error in Terminal:-

```
Internal Server Error: /user_login/
    ....
    ....
    File 
    "/home/rails/projects/DevProject/DataCraft/DataSearch/views.py", 
    line 45, in user_login
    login(request, user)
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Please help me

Comment: Can it be possible if you reassigned `login` and not imported from django library?

Comment: Can you share the model as well

Comment: What about using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm which will handle login process for you?

Comment: I'm using allauth user table and also import `login` in views